# Is it possible to detect the constness of a class' method using SFINAE?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c++11, sfinae

Consider this struct:

```
struct foo {
  void dummy() const {}
};
```

Is it possible to detect the constness of this method using SFINAE?

For example, I would like to capture this property in a trait that could be usable in a `static_assert`:

```
static_assert(is_const_method<decltype(&foo::dummy)>::value, "Not const!");
```

I thought that either `std::is_const` or `std::remove_const` would help me here but they don't seem to encompass this "type" of `const`ness.

Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, looks like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct is_const_method
    : std::false_type
{
};

template <class R, class C, class ...T>
struct is_const_method<R (C::*)(T...)>
    : std::false_type
{
};

template <class R, class C, class ...T>
struct is_const_method<R (C::*)(T...) const>
    : std::true_type
{
};

template <class R, class C, class ...T>
struct is_const_method<R (C::*)(T...) volatile>
    : std::false_type
{
};

template <class R, class C, class ...T>
struct is_const_method<R (C::*)(T...) const volatile>
    : std::true_type
{
};

template <class R, class C, class ...T>
struct is_const_method<R (C::*)(T...) &>
    : std::false_type
{
};

template <class R, class C, class ...T>
struct is_const_method<R (C::*)(T...) const &>
    : std::true_type
{
};

template <class R, class C, class ...T>
struct is_const_method<R (C::*)(T...) volatile &>
    : std::false_type
{
};

template <class R, class C, class ...T>
struct is_const_method<R (C::*)(T...) const volatile &>
    : std::true_type
{
};

template <class R, class C, class ...T>
struct is_const_method<R (C::*)(T...) &&>
    : std::false_type
{
};

template <class R, class C, class ...T>
struct is_const_method<R (C::*)(T...) const &&>
    : std::true_type
{
};

template <class R, class C, class ...T>
struct is_const_method<R (C::*)(T...) volatile &&>
    : std::false_type
{
};

template <class R, class C, class ...T>
struct is_const_method<R (C::*)(T...) const volatile &&>
    : std::true_type
{
};

struct foo {
  void dummy() const {}
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(is_const_method<decltype(&foo::dummy)>::value, "Not const!");
}
```

Comment: Why all the specializations for the non-`const` ones if you're deriving from `false_type` by default anyways?

Comment: Because I'm not as smart as R. Martinho Fernandes. :-)  And I was copy/pasting this together from other bits of code I had already written where I needed to enumerate all of the different possibilities.  It looks tedious until you remember what it was like to try to do this without variadics! :-)

Comment: Argue for `ref_qualifier` and `cv_qualifier` placeholders in templates in the next meeting, please. ;)

Comment: I don't know why I did not think about that first... I must have been searching for something too complicated! Thanks!

Comment: @David `::value` comes from `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`; see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant

Answer (score 11):

You can just use partial specializations.

```
// false by default
template <typename Fun>
struct is_const_function : std::false_type {};

// breakdown member function type
template <typename Class, typename Result, typename... Args>
struct is_const_function<Result (Class::*)(Args...) const> : std::true_type {};
template <typename Class, typename Result, typename... Args>
struct is_const_function<Result (Class::*)(Args...) const volatile> : std::true_type {};
// consider ref-qualified ones for compilers that support it
template <typename Class, typename Result, typename... Args>
struct is_const_function<Result (Class::*)(Args...) const&> : std::true_type {};
template <typename Class, typename Result, typename... Args>
struct is_const_function<Result (Class::*)(Args...) const&&> : std::true_type {};
template <typename Class, typename Result, typename... Args>
struct is_const_function<Result (Class::*)(Args...) const volatile&> : std::true_type {};
template <typename Class, typename Result, typename... Args>
struct is_const_function<Result (Class::*)(Args...) const volatile&&> : std::true_type {};
```

You could also add more specializations to catter for C-style variadic functions, but frankly, my dear, I don't give a damn.